# Detect intent from Entry instead of manual Dialogflow input

Tags: python, tkinter, dialogflow-es

So I have this in Python to detect intents when an input is entered.

```
for text in texts:
    text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(text=text, language_code=language_code)
    query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)
    response = session_client.detect_intent(session=session, query_input=query_input)

    print ('Chatbot: {}\n'.format(response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc",["Hey"],"en-us")
```

And my current gui

```
myText = StringVar()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Chatbot")
window.geometry('400x400')
User_Input = Entry(window, textvariable=myText, width=50).place(x=20, y=350)
subButton = Button(window, text="Send").place(x =350, y=350)
window.mainloop()
```

My aim is to create a GUI that takes a user input, and when submitted the code then detects what the user has input. As you can see from the above, on the final line ["Hey"], this is where I can type whatever I like and the chatbot responds in the console, although it works is not what I'd like to achive.

How would I instead order [""] to detect what the user has wrote in the Entry widget?

Comment: `detect_intent_texts("chat-8","abc",[myText.get()],"en-us")`

Comment: @rioV8 I'll try that now, thank you, , I presume the button then needs a function command too to submit the text, something like 
`def Response():
   result = User_Input.get()`

Comment: Okay @rioV8, that seems to work, what happens is the GUI pops up, I type in what I want, hello for example, then nothing happens.... When I close the GUI and wait 1 second the response is shown in the console. Presumably because `print` is there right?  Any Idea how to show both the input, and output in the GUI? Variety of labels perhaps.

Comment: too much code to type in a comment see answer.

Answer (score 0):

`place()` is only needed for special cases. Better is to use `pack()` or `grid()`.

I don't know what you want to do with the entered result (for text in texts) but here is a working GUI. You need to destroy the main window when you press the "Send" button.

Using the `tk.StringVar().get()` always works for tk and ttk entry widgets. Using `Entry.get()` sometimes gives the empty string.

```
import tkinter as tk

result = None

def Response():
  global result
  result = myText.get()
  window.destroy()

window = tk.Tk()

myText = tk.StringVar()
window.resizable(False, False)
window.title("Chatbot")
window.geometry('400x400')
User_Input = tk.Entry(window, textvariable=myText, width=50).pack()
subButton = tk.Button(window, text="Send", command=Response ).pack()
window.mainloop()

print('Entered:', result)
```

Comment: thank you for getting back, I have done that and get an error:
`NameError: name 'none' is not defined`

Basically, when the user inputs something I want it to show up on the GUI, then when the chatbot responds, it's answer should go underneath the user, and so on.. (think a facebook messenger style) like
User: Hey
Chatbot: Oh Hey
User: How are you.....

Comment: I don't use facebook ;-) Where do you get this `name` error? Then you don't want to destroy the GUI in the `response()` handler. Add a big `tk.Text()` widget and add the new texts to the end of it.

Comment: Neither do I, but it was the only example I could think of :D ...Okay, my bad, I did None as none. 
Okay! Getting there, but now the text isn't showing in the gui at all, it's still showing in the console, presumably because I have said print ('Chatbot:', result), I'd need it to show similar to 
User: Hey
Chatbot: Hi
User: Whats up
All in the GUI. 
Tried something like this but not working:
`botResponse = tk.Label(window,'User:', result)
`

Comment: Add a `tk.Text()` and manipulate its content. Your `tk.Label` will not create the result you want. Have a look at tkinter reference pages.

Comment: Okay @rioV8, the docs I have read suggest something like this, but still struggling to work out how to display the user input and chatbots output in the text:
`def Response():
    global result
    result = myText.get()
    userChat = tk.Text()
    userChat.insert(window, INSERT, CHAR, result)`
Am I on the right track at all?